# Yeoman: error while creating new scaffold with Yeoman

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I am having problem while using Yeoman, I have updated node to 6.2, but still having problem with generating scaffold. It seem that fsevents@1.0.12 is not compatible with my architecture. what can I do ?

This is the output

### $ yo webapp

```
    _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |  'Allo 'allo! Out of the |
`---------´   |    box I include HTML5   |
    ( _´U`_ )    | Boilerplate, jQuery, and |
    /___A___\    | a gulpfile to build your |
    |  ~  |     |           app.           |
__'.___.'__   '--------------------------'
´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

? What more would you like? (Press <space> to select)Sass, Bootstrap, Modernizr
? Choose your style of DSL BDD
create bower.json
create package.json
create gulpfile.js
identical .babelrc
identical .gitignore
identical .gitattributes
identical .bowerrc
identical .editorconfig
create app/favicon.ico
create app/apple-touch-icon.png
create app/robots.txt
create app/styles/main.scss
create app/scripts/main.js
create app/index.html
create test/spec/test.js
create test/index.html


I'm all done. Running npm install & bower install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.3.1 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@3.7.0 install /home/theo/Lin/webapp/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at /home/theo/Lin/webapp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/binding.node

> node-sass@3.7.0 postinstall /home/theo/Lin/webapp/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"/home/theo/Lin/webapp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-46/binding.node" exists. 
testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.

> optipng-bin@3.1.2 postinstall /home/theo/Lin/webapp/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> jpegtran-bin@3.0.6 postinstall /home/theo/Lin/webapp/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node lib/install.js

✔ jpegtran pre-build test passed successfully

> gifsicle@3.0.3 postinstall /home/theo/Lin/webapp/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

✔ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully
/home/theo/Lin/webapp
├─┬ babel-core@6.9.0 
│ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.8.0 
│ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2 
│ │ └── js-tokens@1.0.3 
│ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.9.0 
........................
........................
├── glob@4.5.3 
├── lodash@2.4.2 
├── propprop@0.3.0 
└─┬ through2@0.6.5 
    └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.34 
    └── isarray@0.0.1 

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fsevents is an optional dependency for Mac OSX. You don't need to worry about it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents

Comment: Thanks. I have lost lot of time time to find a solution. It is possible to remove fsevents from package ?